# 2D Array forEach table getting coordinates JTSL, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, onclick, jstl

I got a String[][] which is my playing table (coded Battleship). I display it like this:

```
<%
    String[][] field2 = master.getField(2);
    request.setAttribute("field", field2);
    %>
    <div class=feldbeschreibung>Gegnerisches Feld</div><div class=feldbeschreibung2>Dein Feld</div>
    <table class=player_field2>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${field}" var="row">
                <tr>                
                    <c:forEach items="${row}" var="item">
                        <td class="tdBox" onclick="attack(this, x, y)">
                            <span>${item}</span>
                        </td>       
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmn20.png)

What I do want is to let my method attack() <-*javascript* on what coordinates I'm clicking. I can call the method itself like this:  but I'm missing on which coordinates I'm clicking. Btw I'm pretty new to Java, Javascript, JSP and JTSL (all this is used).

Thanks in advanced :)

Comment: You could use varStatus="xStatus"  which is an attribute available in the forEach tag.   Using it would allow you to use something like onclick="attack(this, ${xStatus.count}, ${yStatus.count})" If you need help, then we could post some demonstration code.

Comment: That's it, thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is demonstration code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="filler"  value="x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x"/> 
<c:set var="field" value="${[filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler,filler]}"/> 
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${field}" var="row" varStatus="xStatus">
                <tr>                
                    <c:forEach items="${row}" var="item" varStatus="yStatus">
                        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">${xStatus.count}:${yStatus.count}</td>       
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```